# How do I install and configure xDebug in magento-docker?

Tags: xdebug

as you know the debugging tool is a one way road for any developer and in this case I bring you this problem that I am trying to solve for a long time and I can't. I am trying to solve it.
I am in a Magento-Docker project where I have the following containers:

[image]

My docker-compose.yml file.

```
    version: '3'

services:
  db:
    container_name: magento-mysql
    image: mysql:${MYSQL_VERSION}
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
       - $PWD/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - my_net_b2c
  nginx:
    container_name: magento-nginx
    tty: true
    build:
      context: $PWD/nginx/${NGINX_VERSION}
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - phpfpm
      - redis:cache
    volumes:
      - $PWD/magento/code:/var/www/html
      - $PWD/nginx/log/error.log:/var/log/nginx/error.log
      - $PWD/nginx/log/access.log:/var/log/nginx/access.log
      - $PWD/nginx/sock:/sock
    networks:
      my_net_b2c:
        ipv4_address: ${NGINX_IP}
  phpfpm:
    container_name: magento-phpfpm
    extra_hosts:
      - ${MOVISTAR_HOST_NAME}:${NGINX_IP}
    build:
      context: $PWD/php/${PHP_VERSION}
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - $PWD/php/${PHP_VERSION}/.composer:/var/www/.composer
      - $PWD/magento/code:/var/www/html
      - $PWD/nginx/sock:/sock
    networks:
      - my_net_b2c
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: magento-elasticsearch
    image: elasticsearch:${ELASTICSEARCH_VERSION}
    restart: always
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    volumes:
      - $PWD/elasticsearch/esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - $PWD/elasticsearch/es_log1:/var/log/elasticsearch
    networks:
      - my_net_b2c
  cron:
    container_name: magento-cron
    build:
      context: $PWD/php/${PHP_VERSION}
    user: root
    command: /usr/local/bin/cronstart
    tty: true
    links:
      - db
      - elasticsearch
      - rabbitmq
    volumes:
      - $PWD/magento/code:/var/www/html
      - $PWD/nginx/sock:/sock
    networks:
      - my_net_b2c
  rabbitmq:
    container_name: magento-rabbitmq
    image: rabbitmq:${RABBITMQ_VERSION}
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER}
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS}
    ports:
      - 15672:15672
      - 5672:5672
    networks:
      - my_net_b2c
  redis:
    container_name: magento-redis
    image: redis:${REDIS_VERSION}
    restart: on-failure:5
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    networks:
      - my_net_b2c
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - "8580:80"
    links:
      - db
    networks:
      - my_net_b2c
      
networks:
  my_net_b2c:
      ipam:
        driver: default
        config:
          - subnet: 172.22.0.0/16
```

I want to install and configure xdebug but I do not know how to configure it and I am struggling with this for a long time since I need it to work, if anyone has a way to help me to follow the configuration would be ideal to contact me and we can do the step by step as it would help me a lot and then I can help a colleague.

Thank you very much and I hope you can help me

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the `docker` build file for your PHP container

```
RUN set -x \
    && pecl install xdebug-3.1.0 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
```

to confirm xdebug is installed run the following in your php container

```
php -m | grep -i xdebug
```

Comment: whats the location of this docker file?